# New to python - trying to chose individual columns from transposed matrix

Tags: python-2.7

So presently code is as so:

```
table = []
for line in open("harrytest.csv") as f:
   data = line.split(",")
   table.append(data)
transposed = [[table[j][i] for j in range(len(table))] for i in range(len(table[0]))]
openings = transposed[1][1: - 1]
openings = [float(i) for i in openings]

mean = sum(openings)/len(openings)
print mean

minimum = min(openings)
print minimum

maximum = max(openings)
print maximum

range1 = maximum - minimum
print range1
```

- This only prints one column of 7 for me, it also leaves out the bottom line. We are not allowed to import with csv module, use numpy, pandas. The only module allowed is os, sys, math & datetime.
- How do I write the code so as to get median, first, last values for any column.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
openings = transposed[1][1: - 1]
```

to this

```
openings = transposed[1][1:]
```

and the last row should appear. You calculations for mean, min, max and range seem correct.

For median you have to sort the row and select the one middle element or average of the two middle elements. First and last element is just `row[0]` and `row[-1]`.